# JavaScript HTML DatePicker

Tags: javascript, html, datepicker

im still new in javascript and learning. I want to create a datepicker using html and javascript. Below is what i have tried and its working, so my question is hw can i do it better. My idea is to create a custom tag in HTML and allow multiple of these tags the javascript will then handle the build and functionality of all the custom tags. Like I said it is working i just want to get some feedback and help making it better.

I have done everything, The HTML and javascript and both working. See below my code

```html
<body>
    <h1>Date Picker</h1>
    <datePicker></datePicker>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='./calendar.js'></script>
</body>
```

```css
.calendar {
    width: 250px;
    background: gainsboro;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.calendarHeaderContainer {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
.topHeader {
    font-size: 20px;
    background: #03A9F4;
    padding: 10px;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}
/*Button Reset*/
button {
    background: none;
    border: none;
}
```

```
let currentDate = new Date();

let currentMonth = currentDate.getMonth();
let currentYear = currentDate.getFullYear();

let months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July","August", "September", "October","November", "December"];
let daysOfTheMonth = ["S","M","T","W","T","F","S"];
var datePickers = document.getElementsByTagName("datePicker");

class Calendar {
    constructor(id,year, month) {
        this.id = id,
        this.year = year,
        this.month = month,
        this.header = months[this.month] + " " + this.year;
    }
    previous(calendarBody,calendarHeader,mainHeader){
        this.year = (this.month === 0) ? this.year - 1 : this.year;
        this.month = (this.month === 0) ? 11 : this.month - 1;
        this.update(calendarBody,calendarHeader,mainHeader)
    }
    next(calendarBody,calendarHeader,mainHeader) {
        this.year = (this.month === 11) ? this.year + 1 : this.year;
        this.month = (this.month + 1) % 12;
        this.update(calendarBody,calendarHeader,mainHeader)
    }
    selectDate(date){

        let year = this.year;
        let month = this.month;
        let newDate =  new Date(year, month, date)
        const newMonth = newDate.toLocaleString('default', { month: 'short' });
        var dayName = newDate.toString().split(' ')[0];
        document.getElementById("topHeader_"+ this.id).innerHTML = dayName+", "+ newMonth + " "+ date
        document.getElementById("input_"+ this.id).value = formatDate(newDate)
    }
    update(calendarBody,calendarHeader,mainHeader){
        let month = currentDate.toLocaleString('default', { month: 'short' });
        let dayName = currentDate.toString().split(' ')[0];
        mainHeader.innerHTML = dayName+", "+ month + " " + currentDate.getDate();

        calendarHeader.innerHTML = months[this.month] + " " + this.year;
        calendarBody.innerHTML = "";
        let firstDay = (new Date(this.year, this.month)).getDay();
            let daysInMonth = 32 - new Date(this.year, this.month, 32).getDate();
            let date = 1;
            for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                let row = document.createElement("tr");
                for (let j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
                    if (i === 0 && j < firstDay) {
                        let cell = document.createElement("td");
                        cell.innerHTML = ""
                        row.appendChild(cell);
                    }
                    else if (date > daysInMonth) {
                        break;
                    }
                    else {
                        let vm = this;
                        let cell = document.createElement("td");
                        let button = document.createElement("button");
                        button.innerHTML = date;
                        cell.appendChild(button);
                        button.addEventListener('click',function(e){

                            vm.selectDate(e.target.innerHTML);
                        });
                        if (date === currentDate.getDate() && this.year === currentDate.getFullYear() && this.month === currentDate.getMonth()) {
                            cell.classList.add("today");
                        }
                        row.appendChild(cell);
                        date++;
                    }
                }
                calendarBody.appendChild(row);
            }
    }
    createPicker(datePicker){
        let vm = this;
        let mainHeader = document.createElement("div");
            mainHeader.setAttribute("id", "topHeader_"+ vm.id)
            mainHeader.classList.add("topHeader");
            mainHeader.innerHTML = vm.header;

        let calendar = document.createElement("div");
            calendar.setAttribute("id", "calendar_"+vm.id);
            calendar.setAttribute("class", "calendar");
            calendar.style.display = "none";

        calendar.appendChild(mainHeader);

        let input = document.createElement("input");
            input.setAttribute("type", "text");
            input.setAttribute("id", "input_"+ vm.id);
            input.setAttribute("tagName", "input");
            input.setAttribute("class", "datePickerInput");
            input.setAttribute("calendar", "calendar_"+vm.id);
            input.setAttribute("placeholder", "Select a date");

        datePicker.appendChild(input);

        let calendarHeaderContainer = document.createElement("div");
        let prevButton = document.createElement("button");
            prevButton.setAttribute("id", "prevButton_"+vm.id);
            prevButton.innerHTML = "<";

        let nextButton = document.createElement("button");
            nextButton.setAttribute("id", "nextButton_"+vm.id);
            nextButton.innerHTML = ">";

        calendarHeaderContainer.appendChild(prevButton);

        let calendarHeader = document.createElement("div");
            calendarHeader.setAttribute("id", "calendar_header_"+vm.id);
            calendarHeader.setAttribute("class", "calendar_header");
            calendarHeader.innerHTML = vm.header;

        calendarHeaderContainer.appendChild(calendarHeader);
        calendarHeaderContainer.appendChild(nextButton);

        let calendarTable = document.createElement("table");
            calendarTable.setAttribute("id", "calendar_body_"+vm.id);

        let calendarTableBody = calendarTable.createTBody();


        let calendarTableHeader = calendarTable.createTHead();
        calendarTableHeader.classList.add("daysOfTheMonth");


            let row = document.createElement("tr");
            for (let j = 0; j < daysOfTheMonth.length; j++) {
                let cell = document.createElement("td");
                cell.innerHTML = daysOfTheMonth[j];
                row.appendChild(cell);
            }
            calendarTableHeader.appendChild(row);
            this.update(calendarTableBody,calendarHeader,mainHeader)


        calendar.appendChild(calendarHeaderContainer);
        calendar.appendChild(calendarTable);

        datePicker.appendChild(calendar);


    input.addEventListener('click',function(e){
        let calendar = document.getElementById(this.getAttribute("calendar"));
        if(calendar.style.display === "none"){
            calendar.style.display = "block"
        }else{
            calendar.style.display = "none"
        }

        });
        nextButton.addEventListener('click',function(e){
            vm.next(calendarTableBody,calendarHeader,mainHeader);
        });

        prevButton.addEventListener('click',function(e){
            vm.previous(calendarTableBody,calendarHeader,mainHeader);
        });


    }
}

function formatDate(date) {
    var d = new Date(date),
        month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
        day = '' + d.getDate(),
        year = d.getFullYear();

    if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
    if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;

    return [year, month, day].join('-');
}

for ( var x = 0; x < datePickers.length; x++) {
   var calendar = new Calendar(x, currentYear, currentMonth);
  calendar.createPicker(datePickers[x])
}
```

One thing i do want to know is. I want to return the selected date for each picker and it also has to be by the id of the picker so you know what date goes where.

Thanks again, everyone.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not just using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date ?

Comment: did you have any styles at all or missed adding it to the post?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes the reason is im learning JavaScript, and as a challenge i want to create a pure javascript html datepicker from scratch not using anything else. If that makes sense.

Comment: @NidhinJoseph, no styles are added yet its just functionality at the moment

Comment: @NidhinJoseph i have added some styles

Comment: "So my question is hw can i do it better"  - this leads me to believe this could be better off on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Also worth a read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components

Comment: I would advise you to not reinvent the wheel. Especially not if you are a JS newbie and want to implement such a complicated thing as a date picker. There are bazillions of date picker libraries out there. Just pick the one that suits you best.

Comment: @yunzen i understand your point, completely. I did this as a challenge, to learn.

Comment: @PeterJoe I think there are better projects to learn JS. Here you have to deal with all the quirks of date management, which are a PITA in every language. This won't teach you much about JS though

Comment: @yunzen i will have to agree and disagree with you. Yes there is better projects, but i have already learned so much doing this project. Yes i agree there is a lot of complex date management stuff, that is one of the things i want to learn. So i do understand what you are saying completely.

Comment: A suggestion for usability: if you want to choose a date in, say, 1974, it would be tedious to go all the way back month by month. So you should establish a way of chosing the year i  a faster manner. A suggestion for programming in general. Read something about Model, View, Controller (MVC) design pattern. This way the responsibilities for input, calculation, data representation and output are divided and encapsulated.

Comment: Also you should rely on the built-in JS date methods instead of doing it on your own. Like `var date1 = new Date('December 17, 1995 03:24:00'); date1.setMonth(date1.getMonth() + 1), console.log(date1) ` `// output:Wed Jan 17 1996 03:24:00`. This way timezone calculations, leap years, leap seconds and all the other stuff will be taking into regard.